# B-2 visa questions

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, dutch-citizens

Here's a little info about my situation:

- Dutch citizen
- Went on J-1 for 3 months in 2016
- Went on ESTA in January for 2 weeks, in  March for 4 days, and in April for 2.5 months in 2017
- Have an American boyfriend in the US, who works for a North-American company
- Not planning on getting married (have been together for under a year)
- Applied for a B-2 visa to start around Sep 1th (paid fee, sent out DS-160, consulate appointment on August 24th)
- Planning to stay less than 3 months, but would like to stay longer, but I've been in the US so much this year already
- Last time I entered the border officer told me that he was "on the fence", but next time I would need a visa
- Stupidly applied for a B-2, but my belief is that I can't cancel anymore
- Planning on doing research for school (BA) during my stay while my boyfriend works
- Need to be back to graduate beginning of next year at my university in the Netherlands and to have a planned mouth surgery
- Have proof of funds of $10,000

Now these are my questions:

- Would it be helpful to push the entry date to Oct or Nov 2017?
- If I'm correct, I can't cancel my appointment anymore without getting an automatic decline for a visa, so not able to use ESTA anymore?
- Are there people that have been in my situation that have advice for me or can tell me about their experience?
- Does anyone know what my chances might be to getting a visa?

Thanks so much! I'm pretty nervous about the interview and I hope that this will help calm my nerves a little bit :)

Comment: I don't think pushing back the entry date slightly would make much of a difference. I think you can cancel your appointment without this counting as a refused visa (but I'm not sure). Travel plans sometimes change, after all.